# On Change or select for form input RADIO type

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have the following in codeigniter:

```
    foreach($created_rates as $rate)
    {
        echo 
            '<div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="'.$rate->id.'" data-rate="'.$rate->rate.'" name="shipmentRate" id="shipmentRate"/>'.str_replace('_', ' ', $rate->service).' $'.$rate->rate.'
                </label>
            </div>';
    }
```

I am trying to get the data-rate via java script, I have the following in java script:

```
<script>
  $("#shipmentRate").on('change', function(){
    var shipmentRate = $(this).data('rate');
    alert(shipmentRate);
  })
</script>
```

This isn't alerting anything or giving any errors in google chrome console

Comment: And you've included jQuery, and that script is after the elements in the DOM, otherwise you're missing a document.ready

Comment: Yes I've included jQuery and yes it is the last thing in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $("input[name=shipmentRate]").on('click', function(){
    var shipmentRate = $(this).data('rate');
    alert(shipmentRate);
  })
```

Your ID is not unique and click is better since change needs a blur to trigger

Comment: It still is not giving me anything at all. https://www.candykingdom.org/checkout and skip to shipping method